# How to make a consistant game loop

Tags: android, loops, view

So in my game my View gets drawn an inconsistent rates. Which in turn makes it glitchy. Ive been running into alot of problems with the invalidate(); meathod. Any simple ideas- Everywhere i look I get thrown up on by tons of intense code.

Comment: your question isn't very descriptive of the problem. Can you post some code? Preferably the main bits of your game engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your game loop doesn't take into account the actual time that has passed between iterations.

The problem is the assumption that there is a fixed amount of time between loop iterations. But this time can be variable depending on the number of objects in the scene, other processes on the computer, or even the computer itself.

This is a common, somewhat subtle, mistake in game programming, but it can easily be remedied. The trick is to store the time at the end of each draw loop and then take the difference of the last update with the current time at the start. Then you should scale all animations and game changes based on the actual elapsed time.

I've wrote more about this on my blog a while back here: http://laststop.spaceislimited.org/2008/05/17/programming-a-pong-clone-in-c-and-opengl-part-i/

Part II specifically covers this issue:
http://laststop.spaceislimited.org/2008/06/02/programming-pong-in-c-and-opengl-part-ii/

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided us with much information, specifically code.

A few things you could do are:

1. Set the initial frame rate to the lowest value you observe your application runs at, i.e., if currently set to 1/60, but the frame rate continuously dips to 1/30, set to 1/30 etc.
2. Rework your drawing calls to be more efficient.
3. Try to combine multiple transformations into a single transformation by multiplying matrices, i.e. if you need to scale, translate, and rotate, multiply those three matrices together and apply that single transformation to the vertices instead of applying three separate transformations.
4. Try not to iterate through entire lists/arrays if unnecessary.
5. Attempt to use the lowest level / most primitive structure possible for anything you have to process in the loop to avoid the overhead of unboxing.

[edit on 2012-08-27]

helpful link for fixing you timestep: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/